# Why docx file is corrupted after editing with npoi

Tags: c#, docx, npoi

I want to edit .docx file and use npoi library.

Is is a snippet:

```
XWPFDocument doc;
using( FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"D:\\template.docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read) ) {
doc = new XWPFDocument(fileStream);
    fileStream.Close();
}

// here can change doc or do nothing

using(FileStream fileStreamNew = new FileStream(@"D:\\test.docx", FileMode.CreateNew)) {
    doc.Write(fileStreamNew);
    fileStreamNew.Close();
}
```

But I get the corrupted file. When I try to open file, modal window is displayed: "We are sorry. We can't open test.docx we found a problem with its content. Details: Unspecified error. Location: /word/header1.xml, Line: 0, Column: 0"

Thank you in advance

============================================================

UPDATE:

Problem is in template file. If I remove images from header & footer then error pass away. But if I put template images back the error return. Any ideas?

=============================================================

UPDATE:

The problem occurs when the image property "Wrap Text" has a value other than "In Line With Text". In my case when the image is background of the text. ('behind text' value).

Comment: If you compare the files in a hex editor (I suggest making *no* changes), are there any obvious differences, such as the output file is all zeroes?

Comment: Thanks guys for reply. Andrew, files have different size. Ehsan, FileMode.Create  don't help.

Comment: @rus Ok, in `using( FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"D:\\template.docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))` line, change `FileAccess.Read` to `FileAccess.ReadWrite`. It might helps you.

Comment: @Ehsan Mohammadi Unfortunately, it doesn't help too.

Comment: @rus Your code works for me perfectly. What's your NPOI version?

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi       NPOI Vesion is 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the file in only using a regular Stream and System.IO.File, then save using FileStream and System.IO.File.

[How to: Create a File or Folder (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-create-a-file-or-folder)
[C# (CSharp) NPOI.XWPF.UserModel.XWPFDocument Code Examples](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/NPOI.XWPF.UserModel/XWPFDocument/-/php-xwpfdocument-class-examples.html)

```
XWPFDocument doc;
using( Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead("D:\\template.docx") ) {
doc = new XWPFDocument(fileStream);
    fileStream.Close();
}


using(FileStream fileStreamNew = File.Create("D:\\test.docx")) {
    doc.Write(fileStreamNew);
    fileStreamNew.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need it.  But I fixed some of those errors relate to the wrap text images in https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/pull/510
I'm not able to catch all the cases, if you found something not caught by it, let me know.